# How to find the integral of an exponential function?

Tags: calculus, integration

What substitution should I use to find the integral of $\frac{4^x - 5^x}{7^x}$?

Comment: the solution should be $${\frac {1}{{{\rm e}^{x\ln  \left( 7 \right) }}} \left( x{{\rm e}^{x
\ln  \left( 7 \right) }}-{\frac {{{\rm e}^{x\ln  \left( 5 \right) }}}{
\ln  \left( 5 \right) -\ln  \left( 7 \right) }} \right) }
$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner,yes it easy to check with http://www.wolframalpha.com/

Comment: this is not true, see my hint, and you can solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

We need $$\int\left(\left(\dfrac47\right)^x-\left(\dfrac57\right)^x\right)dx=\int\left(\dfrac47\right)^xdx-\int\left(\dfrac57\right)^xdx$$

Now $\dfrac{d(a^x)}{dx}=a^x\ln a$ for $a>0$

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
\frac{4^x - 5^x}{7^x}
=\left(\frac{4}{7}\right)^x-\left(\frac{5}{7}\right)^x
=e^{x(\log4-\log7)}-e^{x(\log5-\log7)}
$$
(where $\log$ is to the base $e$) and use the fact that
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{c}e^{cx}\right)=e^{cx}
$$
for $c\neq 0$.